# Showing only two decimals in a numeric result

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have this JavaScript code below for getting the sum value of three text fields.
I need to show two decimal places when showing the result. Please help me.
I have tried so many methods to get decimal places but couldn't find a way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function num(id) {
          var e = document.getElementById(id);
          if (e != null) {
              var v = e.value;
              if (/^\d+$/.test(v)) {
                  return parseInt(v, 10);
              }
          }
          return 0;
      }

      function sum() {
          var v1 = num("contNo6_1");
          var v2 = num("contNo6_2");
          var v3 = num("contNo6_3");

          var r  = document.getElementById("result");
          r.toFixed(2);

          if (r != null) {
              r.value = v1 + v2 + v3;
          }
      }

      function addHandler(element, eventName, handler) {
          if (element.addEventListener) {
              element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
          } else if (element.attachEvent) {
              element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
          }
      }

      addHandler(window, "load",
                 function() {
                   addHandler(document.getElementById("contNo6_1"), "keyup", sum);
                   addHandler(document.getElementById("contNo6_2"), "keyup", sum);
                   addHandler(document.getElementById("contNo6_3"), "keyup", sum);
                 });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your `num()` function return an integer, or zero. You won't get decimal places like that.

Comment: ohh now only I saw, actually this one I took from googling, cud u plz direct me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `num()` function is returning integers or zero, so you'll never get a decimal place to display. Change `num()` to handle floating point numbers like this:

```
function num(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e != null) {
          var v = e.value;
          if (/^[0-9]{1,}\.?[0-9]*$/.test(v)) {  // New regex to accept
                                                 // number with decimal point
             return parseFloat(v);               // parse for Float instead of Int
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gnu6F/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed method in js.

```
var value = 10.123349;
var valueWithTwoDecimal = value.toFixed(2);

/*******
Output : 10.12
*******/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/KggSC/

Comment: The OP already uses `toFixed(2)` in his snippet. You're assuming there are decimal places to be displayed, but his `num()` function doesn't return any.

Comment: @avendra. I have tested before this .toFixed() method but its not working, plz look for the code and if can give me the suitable for that ocde. thnx

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle then ?

Comment: Hi,try this fiddle, this exactly what you want I guess http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/KggSC/